# Grab all swap partitions id & path from the list

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I need to grab all swap partitions form my command

```
blkid
/dev/block/sda4: LABEL="system" UUID="da594c53-9beb-f85c-85c5-cedf76546f7a" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/block/swap0: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/block/swap1: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/block/vnswap0: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/block/zram0: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/block/sde10: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/block/sde11: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/block/sdd13: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="00BC-614E" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/block/sdd17: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="00BC-614E" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/block/sdd22: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1: UUID="9016-4EF8" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/block/loop64: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4"
```

what I need is to grab the path & the UUID of that partition and put them into sperate variables, to know if it is a swap partition TYPE must be TYPE="swap"
the UUID & path value are variable (can change) here's some examples

```
/dev/block/swap0
/dev/block/swap1
/dev/block/swap2
/dev/block/vnswap0
/dev/block/vnswap1
/dev/block/zram0
```

I actually found a code that can do the job but it is copyrighted and I prefer not to use it, so any alternatives are appreciated .. This one is a bit different it looks for swaps in "/proc/swaps"

```
grep zram /proc/swaps
/dev/swap0                              partition       2097148 2816    16383
/dev/zram0                              partition       2097148 2816    16383
/dev/zram1                              partition       2097148 2816    16383
```

I will include it below just for the reference

```
# Find all swapregions and target each one for swapoff
# Don't assume it's in the first field of swaps, find it
    SR="\/dev\/"
    PS="/proc/swap*"

    DIE=`awk -v SBD="$SR" ' $0 ~ SBD {
          for ( i=1;i<=NF;i++ )
            {
              if ( $i ~ ( "^" SBD ) )
               {
                  printf "%s;", $i
               }
            }
          }' $PS`

    saveifs=$IFS
    IFS=';'

    # I could have put all this in awk and just eval'd it 
    # But where's the fun in that

    for i in $DIE
    do
        case $i in
            *zram*)
                  j=`echo $i | sed 's/.*zram//'`
                 ( ( 
                     echo $j > /sys/class/zram-control/hot_remove
                     echo 1 > /sys/block/zram${j}/reset
                     swapoff $i
                  ) & )
                  ;;
            *)
                  if [ -n $i ]; then
                      ( ( swapoff $i ) & ) 
                  fi
                  ;;
        esac
    done

    IFS=$saveifs

    exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following(I am driving right now so didn't test it, will test it once I reach home too :) ).

```
awk '$0 ~ /swap/ && match($0,/\/[^:]*/){path=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);match($0,/UUID=\"[^"]*/);print path,substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6);path=""}'  Input_file
```

As per OP 2 variables needed so adding solutions as per that also now.

```
uuids=$(awk '$0 ~ /swap/ && match($0,/UUID=\"[^"]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)}'  Input_file)
paths=$(awk '$0 ~ /swap/ && match($0,/\/[^:]*/){substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file)
```

Comment: @ranger003, could you please try this solution and let me know then?

Comment: @ranger003, oh sorry forgot `/` try now and let me know then?

Comment: Now it outputs the path of every single partitions

Comment: @ranger003, ok so in case you need only `swap` ones then try my edit one now and let me know then?

Comment: Works perfect only grabbed swap partition paths. Now how to do the same to grab the UUID for swap partitions.

Comment: @ranger003, you asked for path and UUID both I believe, now you need only 1 of them please confirm once?

Comment: Yes I want both but I want to extract them separately, then later assign the paths to a variable and UUIDs into another variable

Comment: @ranger003, could you please try using 1st: `paths=$(awk '$0 ~ /swap/ && match($0,/\/[^:]*/){substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file)` AND then 2nd one:
`uuids=$(awk '$0 ~ /swap/ && match($0,/UUID\"[^"]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)}'  Input_file)` and let me know then?

Comment: `uuids=$(awk '$0 ~ /swap/ && match($0,/UUID=\"[^"]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)}'  Input_file)` try this for uuids and let me know then?

Comment: @ranger003, I have added both solutions in answer now, please check and let me know then?

Answer (score 0):

script.awk

```
/TYPE="swap"/ {
  path = $1
  uuid = $2
  sub(":", "", path)
  sub("UUID=\"", "", uuid)
  sub("\"", "", uuid)
  print path, uuid
}
```

Returns the following result: e.g. `blkid | awk -f script.awk`

```
/dev/block/swap0 57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b
/dev/block/swap1 57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b
/dev/block/vnswap0 57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b
/dev/block/zram0 57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Could you edit that so I don't need calling an external file ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl, just use the "command" instead of "cat ranger.txt"

```
/tmp> cat ranger.txt
blkid
/dev/block/sda4: LABEL="system" UUID="da594c53-9beb-f85c-85c5-cedf76546f7a" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/swap0: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="swap"
/dev/block/swap1: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="swap"
/dev/block/vnswap0: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="swap"
/dev/block/zram0: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="swap"
/dev/block/sde10: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/sde11: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/sdd13: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="00BC-614E" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/block/sdd17: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="00BC-614E" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/block/sdd22: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1: UUID="9016-4EF8" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/block/loop64: UUID="57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b" TYPE="ext4"
/tmp> cat ranger.txt | perl -ne ' /(^.+?):.*UUID=\"(.+?)\".*TYPE=\"swap\"/g and print "$1 $2\n" '
/dev/block/swap0 57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b
/dev/block/swap1 57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b
/dev/block/vnswap0 57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b
/dev/block/zram0 57f8f4bc-abf4-655f-bf67-946fc0f9f25b
/tmp>
```